# Python code run error Need help. It gives error that "cannot import name 'keys'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys

driver = webdriver.firefox()
driver.get ("http://www.python.org")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pselenium/sample.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
ImportError: cannot import name 'keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' (C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\keys.py)
```

I traced the path manually and all the file names and path are correct. I dont know what is the problem.

Answer (score 10):

You should only specify "keys" once:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
```

Edit:

Are you trying to import "Keys" (capitalized)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: This is correct I was facing a similar issue and it was ```from selenium.webdriver.common import keys``` that resolved the python traceback.

Answer (score 3):

from selenium import webdriver  (**all in small letters**)

from selenium.webdriver.common.**keys** import **Keys**

(first letter in first keyword 'keys' must be small and first letter in second keyword 'Keys' must be in capital).